# Why int/int = int?

Tags: c++, c

Why when I divide two integer numbers the result is an integer and not a float, why was this design decision chosen?

Comment: What if I want integral division? What do I do then?

Comment: It matches the decision made by CPU designers.

Comment: Frankly because it makes the most sense. If you added two `int` would you expect an `int` to be returned? Of course! Same with all other mathematical operations, so why would they make an exception for division?

Comment: @Borgleader: That could have been a separate operator (like, for example, `//` in Python 3).

Comment: It is technically called "integer division" in this case. My opinion is that integer division was preferred for performance and hardware reasons. It is very expensive to do floating-point calculations (which would be needed for "real" division).

Comment: @EudisDuran No, both C and C++ allow all kinds of implicit type conversions.

Comment: @Cyber It doesn't really just "make sense". It is more to do with the efficiency of integer division. You can always ask for floating point division if you need it. But one divided by two being zero is most unintuitive mathematically. The designers of python decided to do it differently in python 3.

Comment: @EudisDuran That has nothing to do with it.

Comment: Casting an `int` to a `float` can involve a loss of precision.  IEEE 754 Single-precision floats can only exactly represent integer numbers between ±2²⁴.  If you want a float, then you have to tell it you want a float.

Comment: The resulting type of applying this operation on two numbers is the type of more complex one. Applying it on two `int`s returns `int`. That would be integer division.

Comment: I think Homer Simpson explained it best when he told Bart the story of Hercules and the Lion.....  "It was the olden days".  http://www.tvfanatic.com/quotes/dont-you-know-the-story-of-hercules-and-the-lion-is-it-a-bib/

Comment: Voting to re-open. There's a reason for this choice, and it isn't a matter of opinion. It may be a duplicate though.

Comment: @juanchopanza, the difference is that C is a "Do as I say" language, insofar as it does not attempt to hide the realities of hardware too much.  Python, on the other hand, is a "do what I mean" language, which is entirely designed to hide the difficulties in implementation.  Neither approach is right or wrong, they are just design choices.

Comment: @Mitch My point being that it integer division is not used because "it makes sense". It is used for other reasons.

Comment: Nothing in early C resulted in a `float`.  Asking "Why...result is an integer and not a `double` (or floating point) would make more sense.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

When early C was being designed, a lot of contemporary hardware did not have floating-point support.

When floating-point types were added to C over its predecessors ([BCPL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BCPL) and B), the integer semantics of the division operator were left unchanged.

The [BCPL manual](http://cm.bell-labs.com/who/dmr/bcpl.pdf) makes for an interesting read (emphasis mine):

> 5.1 Arithmetic Expressions
>
> Syntactic form:
>
> `E1 * E2` or `E1 / E2` or `E1 rem E2` or `E1 + E2` or `+E1` or `E1 - E2` or `-E1`
>
> Semantics: All these operators interpret the Rvalues of their operands as signed integers, and **all yield integer results**.
>
> …
>
> The division operator `/` yields the correct result of [the division of `E1` by `E2` if `E1` is divisible by `E2`; it is otherwise implementation dependent but the rounding error is never greater than 1.
>
> The operator `rem` yields the remainder of `E1` divided by `E2`; its exact specification is Implementation dependent.

It is clear that portability was not a concern and the language was allowed to do whatever the underlying hardware did.

Even today there are plenty of platforms that support C but have no floating-point hardware (for example, small embedded platforms).

Some modern higher-level languages choose to define `int / int` as floating-point division. For example, Python 3 does, and has a separate operator, `//`, for integer division. Interestingly, that integer division operator has [rounding rules that are different to its C counterpart](http://python-history.blogspot.co.uk/2010/08/why-pythons-integer-division-floors.html). [*]

If you are interested in the history of C, take a look at [The Development of the C Language](http://cm.bell-labs.com/who/dmr/chist.html) by Dennis Ritchie.

[*] Python integers are also interesting in that they are [arbitrary-precision](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arbitrary-precision_arithmetic).